# PHP DOMDocument skips even elements

Tags: php, domdocument

Hello I'm using this method to replace all iframe and img tags with span tags

```
    $string = clean($string);
    $dom = new \DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    $iframes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe');

    foreach($iframes as $iframe) {
        $src = $iframe->getAttribute('src');
        $span = $dom->createElement('span');
        $span->setAttribute('title', $src);
        $span->setAttribute('class', 'lazy-youtube');
        $iframe->parentNode->replaceChild($span, $iframe);
    }

    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach($images as $image) {
        $src = $image->getAttribute('src');
        $span = $dom->createElement('span');
        $span->setAttribute('title', $src);
        $span->setAttribute('class', 'lazy-image');
        $image->parentNode->replaceChild($span, $image);
    }

    $html = $dom->saveHTML();

    return clean($html);
```

but problem is that it skips elements it's always like this

```
// Iframe
<span>
<iframe>
<span>
<iframe>
<span>
<iframe>
<span>
<iframe>

// Img
<span>
<img>
<span>
<img>
<span>
<img>
<span>
<img>
```

Html for iframes

```
<div class="content">
<p>
   <iframe frameborder="0" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T6kG5vuPVSs?rel=0" width="560"></iframe>
<p>
</p>
   <iframe frameborder="0" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GjnadPBMJGs?rel=0" width="560"></iframe>
<p>
</p>
   <iframe frameborder="0" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KYm8SLLQ0kk?rel=0" width="560"></iframe>
<p>
</p>
   <iframe frameborder="0" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xUVz4nRmxn4?rel=0" width="560"></iframe>
<p>
</p>
   <iframe frameborder="0" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hmZ6ziQJByY?rel=0" width="560"></iframe>
</p>
</div>
```

All same type of elements have same attributes, only src is different. Anyone know how can I fix it to replace all elements?

Comment: Probably when you replace the element, the array/object changes, shifting the remaining in one spot, skiping the next. That's why _I think_ it's skipping .

Comment: @FirstOne and how can I fix this?

Comment: @FirstOne Im using this method when storing html in database, by not efficient you mean, It wouldn't work all the time or it would take alot of time to render it?

Comment: @FirstOne I tried your code, and it just made an infinite loop

Comment: Take a look at this test code: [https://eval.in/605263](https://eval.in/605263). Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @FirstOne Yes, Thank you! Works like a charm, and about effiency I hope it will not make trouble because I have an limits to how much iframes and images can be posted at same time (10 of each type)

Comment: I'll delete all my previous comments and create an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation** of the problem: It's probably skipping every other element because once you remove an iframe, for example, the object (the list of elements) changes in a way that all other iframes shift to ocuppy the removed's spot.

One way to **fix** it:

```
// code
$iframes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
while($iframes->length > 0){ // while there are still frames left to change
    foreach($iframes as $iframe) {
        // your regular code to replace iframe with span
        // break; // this makes it easier to understand, but not really necessary
    }
    $iframes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe'); // get the (remaining) skipped frames until there is none left
}
// code
```

*Don't forget to do the same with the images.*

---

---

Here is a better way to understand the problem:

```
 1 - List of iframes
 iframe1  iframe2  iframe3  iframe4 iframe5 [...]
    /\ - current item in loop

 2 - Replacing iframe1, it comes out of the list (since I just want iframes), so the list is now:
 iframe2  iframe3  iframe4  iframe5 [...]
    /\

 3 - Loop continues and it goes to the next item
 iframe2  iframe3  iframe4  iframe5 [...]
             /\ - current item in loop
```

See how, that way, it would skip every other element?

Comment: There's no need to get the remaining skipped frames if you get the DOMNodeList item instead. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the foreach does not make a copy of the iterated object and the DOMNodeList element gets modified when you replace the child.
The correct way of iterating the DOMNodeList is:

```
$elements = $domElement->getElementsByTagName("iframe");
while($elements->length > 0) {
    $oldNode = $elements->item(0);
    $newNode = $dom->createElement("image");
    $oldNode->parentNode->replaceChild($oldNode, $newNode);
}
```

Using the same logic, if you need to move the child elements from the old node to the new one, you can do this:

```
while($oldNode->childNodes->length > 0)
    $newNode->appendChild($oldNode->childNodes->item(0));
```