# Why does preg_replace return NULL when I'm trying to replace a tags with titles?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to replace the links with just the text and resave the content, but only when it meets the below requirements. However, when I use the `preg_replace` function it returns `NULL` even though I was able to replace the links with the text by using `array_replace($fullLinks,$linksRemoved)`.

I have removed the `array_replace` as I did not know how to put the new array back in the content.

I have already gone through all the other "`preg_replace` returning NULL" posts but wasn't able to find a solution that works for me. When searching for a pattern, I assume that "hello I'm the title" is also a pattern, or is that where I'm going wrong?

```
$post_id = 122232;
$content_post = get_post($post_id);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$linksRemoved[] = array();
$FullLinks[] = array();

// preg_match_all('/<a.*href=\"(.*)\".*><\/a>/isU', $content, $matches);
// above only returns 11 links
$regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $content, $matches)) {
    $avoidImages  = array('.jpg', '.png', '.gif', '.jpeg', 'glossary');
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match){
        if($match == str_replace($avoidImages, '', $match)){
            if (strpos($match, 'bush.com') == true || strpos(match, 'articles') == true){

                $fullLinks[] = array('match' => $match );
                $linksRemoved[] = array('links' => strip_tags($match) );




            }
        }
    }
}
$linksRemoved = array_filter($linksRemoved);
$content = preg_replace($fullLinks, $linksRemoved, $content);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($content);
echo '</pre>';
```

I already tried using DOMDocument but kept getting stuck where replaceChild skipped even elements like here: [PHP DOMDocument skips even elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372233/php-domdocument-skips-even-elements)

`$linksRemoved` array example below:
`$fullLinks` array is the same, but the words are hyperlinked so it includes the  markup.

```
 [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["match"]=>
    string(114) "gluteus medius"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["match"]=>
    string(174) "gluteal complex"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["match"]=>
    string(130) "rectus abdominis"
  }
```

Comment: HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: I tried that, but I ran into this a similar problem to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372233/php-domdocument-skips-even-elements.  Appreciate your feedback and might need to give that one another shot then. Thanks.

Comment: To whoever -ed the question, can you please explain why? I'm trying to learn and I'm not sure why my question received negative feedback. I did do my research and tried to structure the question as clearly as possible.

Comment: `null` usually indicates an error. What does `preg_last_error()` give?

Comment: thanks @Jim , it's saying `int(0)` , so I'll go through it again and see where I went wrong.

Comment: Show some sample input lines. What does dump of `$fullLinks` and `$linksRemoved` give?

Comment: OK, fair point - will add these now. Sadly though, the negative feedback now removed the privilege to ask any questions in the future, so it would have been nice just gave me a heads-up instead ... if that was the reason for the -1.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I can give a plus :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK  preg_replace doesn't work with multi-level arrays, change these 2 lines

```
$fullLinks[] = array('match' => $match );
$linksRemoved[] = array('links' => strip_tags($match) );
```

into

```
$fullLinks[] = $match;
$linksRemoved[] = strip_tags($match);
```